# Exact text filtering while using selection box in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an selection box with some status, based on the change of the status, the item should be iterated but the issue is the angularjs filter functionality not matching the exact text.

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="sampleController">
<div>
<select ng-model="test" ng-change="getfilter()">

  <option ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.status}}</option>

</select>
<ul>

  <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:test">{{item.name}}</li>

</ul>
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

Controller

```
function sampleController($scope){

   $scope.list = [
  {name: "item1", status: "shipped"},
  {name: "item2", status: 'Partially Shipped '}
  ];

  $scope.getfilter = function(){



  }

}
```

jsbin : http://jsbin.com/amuwol/2/edit

when i select 'shipped' status i need to get only 'item1' but currently i am getting both 'item1' and 'item2'. I just defined the getfilter function and stopped there since i didnt get idea to proceed further.

Please provide me the solution to proceed further

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered if the answer resolved your issue?

Answer (score 3):

The filter does work correctly. That is not the cause of the issue that you face.
When you select `shipped` in the select tag, the reason why the second option is also shown is because the status of the second item contains the word "shipped" - "Partially **Shipped**". Moreover, you have chosen the case insensitive option.

You have some choices:

- Use a different status, something like a number that indicates if the item is shipped or partially shipped. Ensure that no sub-character or number occurs in more than one status. That way, selecting one option will indeed filter out the non-relevant items.
- The preferred option - pass a third parameter to the filter. This third parameter will tell the filter if it should be case sensitive or not. So you can use something like:
  `<li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:test:true">`
  The "true" parameter tells Angular to be case sensitive. This will fail if instead of `Partially Shipped"` you change the case to `"partially shipped"` - that is, the lowercase "shipped" is used instead of the uppercase.
  [Bin](http://jsbin.com/amuwol/4/edit)

EDIT: As pointed out below, the setting of "true" parameter to allow the filter to be case sensitive is not supported currently in the stable released of AngularJS

Comment: pls be aware that case sensitive filter is relatively new. E.g. it isn't supported in 1.0.7

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement your own filter because angular's default filter uses toLowerCase(). sth. like

```
filters.filter('exactString', function() {
return function(string, term) {
    return ('' + string).indexOf(term) > -1;
}});
```

JsFiddle for angular 1.0.7: http://jsfiddle.net/alfrescian/7sMQ8/